# Call a CodeBehind Method from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel, code-behind

i am trying to learn the MVVM design pattern by coding a little App using Xamarin.Forms.
I safe all the data in the Android File-System (XML) to make it persistent. But at the moment all the methods to safe the Data are in the ViewModel and i am trying to move those Methods to the CodeBehind (Model) in order to respect the MVVM design pattern.

After i moved all the Methods to the CodeBehind i am not able to call the functions within my ViewModel even though they are within the same namespace and declared as public.

The Method `DeleteCar(...)` within my ViewModel tries to call the method `ToCarsFile(...)` which is in CodeBehind:

```
public void DeleteCar(object sender)
{
    AllCars.Remove(sender as Car);
    ToCarsFile(AllCars); //This is underlined in red
}
```

CodeBehind (.xaml.cs):

```
public void ToCarsFile(ObservableCollection<Car> CarsList)
{
    --SOME CODE FOR DATA PERSISTENCE--
}
```

I get the error "Error CS0103: The name 'ToCarsFile' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (ProjectCars)"

Probably a stupid mistake but what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why do you think moving code into the code-behind is part of the MVVM concept?  Saving data is certainly something you can do in your VM.  Your VM should not be calling methods of your code behind, that is breaking MVVM principals.  Finally, you need a reference to an instance of a class in order to use it's public methods.  This is basic C#

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the answer. I made a mistake when i posted that question. I had an instance... I will update that. Regarding the MVVM Concept: I thought that the CodeBehind and the Model are the same and since the Model is responsible for the the application data i wanted to move that part of the Code to the CodeBehind. Seems my MVVM understanding is my mistake here :) Thank you

Comment: the code behind is part of the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things going on here:

1st. Since functions are declared in classes, then you need an instance of the class to call it

```
public class SomeModel {
    public void ToCarsFile(ObservableCollection<Car> CarsList)
    {
    --SOME CODE FOR DATA PERSISTENCE--
    }
}
```

So to call it, you need something like this

```
   var modelObject = new SomeModel();
   modelObject.ToCarsFile(/*data*/);
```

2. Your xaml.cs should not be your model. Both ViewModel and Model should be independent from the view (the xaml.cs class is your view class)

So there is something in your MVVM wiring that needs some refining

Comment: Hi @Athanasios Kataras, thanks for the quick answer. Regarding my "Instance mistake": I made a mistake when i posted this question. I will update that. Regarding the MVVM: Thanks for that information. I will go through some more articles and fix my MVVM.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote/accept answers.